# Shader tester iOS App?

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore

Will Apple reject an app which renders a 3D scene that allows you to modify and compile GLSL ES shaders by editing them in the app? (something not unlike e.g. http://shadertoy.com, but native OpenGL ES 2)

What about if it registers for a file type and opens .vsh and .fsh files as documents?

I know that it may be problematic if the app automatically downloads shader code from a server (and then runs it), but the answer is not so clear for these other approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Shaderific](http://www.shaderific.com/features/) allows you to "*import shader files with Dropbox or iTunes Document Sharing"* so they were allowed, but the bad news is that you have at least one strong competitor.

Answer (score 1):

Unless a similar app is already published on the App Store, it is fairly impossible to determine where Apple's line will be without talking to Apple. Even if there are similar apps already published, it does not mean Apple will not reverse itself and start removing apps of a certain type or rejecting update submissions.